# Groovy Grails standalone application without tomcat or any other servlet container

Tags: java, spring-boot, grails, groovy, executable-jar

I am new in groovy/grails and want to make a **Standalone App** utilising just **Grails** i.e. an Executable Jar without a Servlet Container.

It is possible in *spring* with `@SpringBootApplication` and `SpringApplication.run()` and adding this to maven pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible to do it in Grails alone without using springBoot?

 if yes, how?

 if no, why not?

Comment: If you want a standalone application why even include the web parts? If you don't include the web parts no container will be started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Grails tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails),

> Grails is an Open Source, full stack, web application framework that ...

If it's not web then, it doesn't make much sense to go with Grails. I suppose, you're interested in a CLI application. I would suggest [Micronaut](https://docs.micronaut.io/), instead; particularly, refer to the section, [Standalone Command Line Applications](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#commandLineApps).

**Helpful resources:**

- [Picocli](https://picocli.info/), A one-file framework for creating Java CLI applications
- [Integration betweem Micronaut and Picocli](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-picocli/latest/guide/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Grails is not meant to run outside a JEE container normally.

On the other hand you can theoretically create a Fat Jar packaged with embedded tomcat/jetty and run it as a standalone jar. It might work, but I didn't test it.

If you want to go hack-free way, you can pick Micnonaut as the closest Grails alternative, which is running on `netty` and thus doesn't need container.

Another option would be to use [Ratpack](https://ratpack.io/) which is also Groovy flavored and `netty`-based.

I had some good experience recently with a mix of [standalone GORM](http://gorm.grails.org/) and [Vert.x](https://vertx.io/) (I had some specific requirements for async)